# Download and install mean v 0.3 in ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, meanjs

I am trying to install mean 0.3 version but every tutorials gives me the option to install only version 0.4 can any one list out the steps to install version 0.3 ??
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't install version 0.3 as they have merged the version with the latest version. Try using 0.4 as it has some fine improvements. Though the work is still going on the generator crud modules.